# Can we use multiple Angular versions in an Application?

Tags: angular

We have an older application, which was developed in Angular 4, having multiple tabs with corresponding operations. 
Now, we have got a requirement to implement a new functionality in a new tab. We are thinking to use latest Angular version(9) for this development. 
Can we develop our new functionality with angular 9 features and can integrate with older Angular 4 application?/
As the application is developed on Angular 4, we need to use the same version for the development?/
Is it easy to migrate the entire application to Angular 9, without impacting current functionality(without code change - as it is huge application, any changes would need to test the whole app again)?

Please let me know..
Thanks.

Comment: you can't use different angular versions in the same app. A migration from 4 to 9 can be a large undertaking or a very small one. The effort required is very app specific. But the longer you put it off, the more tech debt you accumulate. The biggest changes from 4 to 9 will be the http client and your rxjs version. You'll need to use compat for rxjs or migrate every observable you have

Comment: @bryan60 is right, and I would suggest you to create this tab in Angular 4, if you want to evolve technology you could create a new APP in Angular 9 and show each one (ng4 and ng9) in a HTML IFRAME inside the Tabs meanwhile you migrate your Angular 4 to Angular 9. Since it's a huge APP it will take time to migrate.

Comment: Fortunately there is the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/#4.0:9.0) that assists you along way